# Where is the root morpheme in Middle English talon (talon, claw) and muscheron (mushroom)?

Tags: morphology, middle-english

Is it possible to consider *-on*, *-eron* as suffixes (as they are in Middle French)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The etymologies for *[talon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=talon)* and *[mushroom](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mushroom)* are not completely settled, but in both cases it seems clear that the Middle English word (*talon* or *mussheron*) was imported (from Old French) in its full form:

- the Old French *talon* comes from Latin *talonem*, from *talus* (my French *Littré* qualifies *talonem* of “fictious form of *talus*”, etymonline calls it “Middle Latin”).
- *mussheron* is reported to come from Anglo-French *musherun*, “perhaps from Late Latin *mussirionem*”

As such, it doesn't seem logical to consider *-on* or *-eron* as English suffixes. At least, not on the basis of these two examples.

---

There is one modern use of *-on* as a suffix, which is unrelated to your question as I understand it, in science. The *New Oxford American Dictionary* says:

> **-on** (suffix, Physics, Biochemistry & Chemistry, forming nouns)
>
> 1. denoting subatomic particles or quanta: *neutron*, *photon*.
> 2. denoting molecular units: *codon*.
> 3. denoting substances: *interferon*.

Comment: Um...somehow I don't think that disproves -on or -eron as a suffix in Middle French.

Comment: @Third Idiot: please read again. The question isn't about Middle French (1. it would be off topic; 2. *-on* and *-eron* sure **are** suffixes in Middle French, as they are in Modern French). It's about Middle English, in which *-on* and *-eron* are not suffixes to my understanding: those two examples don't show it, and I know of no example that would show it.

Comment: Yep, Understood. BTW, could you perhaps show that "talon", and "muscheron" are not derivatives?

Comment: Thank you, everyone, especially Third idiot. That's the way I thought and considered those two words as roots in ME. I appreciate it much that you confirmed my ideas concerning morphemic analysis!!!